# imwrite does not accept second argument

Tags: image, matlab

I am new to MATLAB. I am using imwrite to write an image in the specific folder which user selected, but it is giving me following error

```
Error using imwrite>parse_inputs
The colormap should have three columns.
Error in imwrite (line 440)
[data, map, filename, format, paramPairs] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
```

My code is

```
imwrite(latest_data,userpath,'bmp');
```

Where the userpath is as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You need to use a char (`'single quotes'`) instead of a string (`"double quotes"`) in your file path. You can either make this the case when defining the `userpath` variable, or use `char(userpath)` when inputting to `imwrite`.

This bug appears to have been fixed by R2018b, so likely an issue between R2016b (when strings were introduced) up to at least R2017b (tested).

**Explanation**

This looks like slightly unexpected behaviour from the `imwrite` function because of a quirk of how the inputs are parsed.

From the [`documentation`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html), there are 3 main ways of calling the function

```
imwrite(A,filename)
imwrite(A,map,filename)
imwrite(___,fmt)
```

In particular for the last one,

> `imwrite(___,fmt)` writes the image in the format specified by fmt, regardless of the file extension in filename. **You can specify `fmt` after the input arguments in any of the previous syntaxes.**

You are trying to do the 3rd case, i.e. `imwrite(A,filename,fmt)`, which should be valid. Unfortunately the error makes it seem like Matlab is detecting the 2nd case of inputs `imwrite(A,map,filename)`, since the error message reports that `map` is invalid, because your `filename` is not a valid colormap.

Typically, Matlab functions which accept an increasing number of arguments retain the same input ordering as the number of inputs increase, which makes the variables unambiguous. That's not the case here, as **the case of 3 inputs can be interpreted two different ways.**

However, taking a hint from [this on MATLAB Answers](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/411305-could-someone-help-me-with-the-imwrite-command-please-error-using-imwrite-parse_inputs-line#answer_329627), the error message is misleading. **`imwrite` does not support string inputs.**

In fact, if you `edit imwrite`, you can see that the **input parsing relies on `ischar` to work out which of the two 3-input cases you're trying to use.** Where `varargin` is a variable number of inputs, this is used to determine which is the first *string* (a confusing variable name from before string variables existed and everything was a char):

So if you use a char for the filepath input then the desired 3-input case will be chosen.

```
firstString = [];
for k = 1:length(varargin)
    if (ischar(varargin{k}))
        firstString = k;
        break;
    end
end
```

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me!

Comment: @Cris "slightly unexpected behaviour" might be my kind way of saying "ugh not another string related incompatibility bug!"

Comment: @Cris I logged a bug with MathWorks and checked various versions I have installed - turns out this bug was resolved from R2018b+ (with a call to `convertStringsToChars` before doing the `ischar` input parsing), I've edited my question to reflect this